# CMake linking error (collect2: ld returned 1 exit status) /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpression

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, linker, linker-errors

The project structure is as below

```
├── ast
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── expression
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── Expression.cpp
│   │   ├── Expression.hpp
│   │   ├── NumericExpression.cpp
│   │   └── NumericExpression.h
│   ├── Visitor.cpp
│   └── Visitor.hpp
├── callSlang
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── contexts
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Context.hpp
│   ├── Symbol.cpp
│   ├── Symbol.hpp
│   └── SymbolTable.hpp
├── frontend
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Parser.cpp
│   └── Parser.hpp
├── Makefile
├── meta
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── Meta.hpp
└── README.md
```

##### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

# set the project name
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740678/cmake-error-in-findterminfo-with-clang-15-on-macos
project(slangLLvm VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")


set(LLVM_DIR /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/cmake/llvm)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG
             PATHS ${search_paths}
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH)



add_subdirectory(meta)
add_subdirectory(contexts)
add_subdirectory(ast)
add_subdirectory(frontend)
add_subdirectory(callSlang)
```

##### callSlang/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCE_FILE main.cpp)
# add the files for creating executable
add_executable(slangLLVM ${SOURCE_FILE})


#link the libs 
target_link_libraries(slangLLVM 
PRIVATE
    ast
    frontend
)
```

##### ast/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCE_FILES Visitor.cpp)
add_library(ast ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(ast 
PUBLIC 
    meta
    contexts
    LLVMSupport
    expression
PRIVATE
    frontend
)

    
# get the include dirs 
target_include_directories(ast 
INTERFACE  
    .
PUBLIC
    ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/meta 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ast/expression
    
)

add_subdirectory(expression)
```

##### expression/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCE_FILES Expression.cpp NumericExpression.cpp)
add_library(experssion ${SOURCE_FILES})


target_link_libraries(experssion
PUBLIC
    ast
)
    
# get the include dirs 
target_include_directories(experssion 
INTERFACE  
    .
PUBLIC 
    ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contexts
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ast 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/meta

)

# INTERFACE tells to use includes to other libs but on the ast
```

##### frontend/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCE_FILES Parser.cpp)

add_library(frontend STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(frontend 
PRIVATE 
    ast 
)

# get the include dirs 
target_include_directories(frontend 
INTERFACE 
    .
PRIVATE
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ast
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contexts
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ast/expression
)
```

##### meta/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(meta INTERFACE)    
# get the include dirs 
target_include_directories(meta INTERFACE .)
```

This compiles without error but fails during linking with the following error

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable slangLLVM
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpression
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [callSlang/CMakeFiles/slangLLVM.dir/build.make:93: callSlang/slangLLVM] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nithin/learn/c-cpp/slang-llvm/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:392: callSlang/CMakeFiles/slangLLVM.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nithin/learn/c-cpp/slang-llvm/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nithin/learn/c-cpp/slang-llvm/build'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

CallSlang depends on ast, ast depends on the expression and vice versa.

I have tried the solution in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062843/cmake-linking-error-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status) but it not-working so far for me. I am really new to CMake. Is it caused by the circular call by ast and expression, if so how can correct the same?
The complete code can be found in this [link](https://github.com/nithinivi/C-CPP_Learn/tree/slang-llvm/slang-llvm)

Could someone please tell me the possible cause and solution? If I've missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point, please let me know in the comments. Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Comment: @273K Are u suggesting in ast/CMakeLists.txt? If so I have tried it out and getting the same error.

Comment: Your library target is called `experssion` but your   project links to `expression`. Fix your typo and it should work.

Comment: @273K: CMake perfectly allows to use `target_link_libraries` for link with targets which are not created yet, so order between `target_link_libraries` and `add_subdirectory` is not important. Only the very first argument to `target_link_libraries` should denote an already existed target.